# MYSQL Return Values from Same Table based on a Scale ID

Tags: mysql

Input Table:

```
onetsoc_code | element_id | scale_id | data_value 
11-1011.00 | 2.A.1.a | IM | 4.38
11-1011.00  2.A.1.a LV  4.75
11-1011.00  2.A.1.b IM  4.38
11-1011.00  2.A.1.b LV  4.88
11-1011.00  2.A.1.c IM  4.12
11-1011.00  2.A.1.c LV  4.50
```

Desired Output Table:

```
onetsoc_code | element_id | data_value
11-1011.00 | 2.A.1.b | 4.88
11-1011.00 | 2.A.1.a | 4.75
11-1011.00 | 2.A.1.c | 4.50
```

Explanation:

I have a table which contains 15k rows referenced by a group_id and then within the group_id, an element_id. I want to do a two part query which gets all elements of a certain group_id for 1 specific element_id, sort them, then get elements of another element_id based on the order they were returned in the last query.

```
SELECT element_id, data_value 
FROM skills 
WHERE element_id 
IN(SELECT CAST(group_concat(CONCAT('''', element_id, '''') ORDER BY data_value DESC) as         char) FROM `skills` WHERE onetsoc_code = '11-1011.00' AND scale_id = 'IM')
AND onetsoc_code = '11-1011.00' 
AND scale_id = 'LV'
```

I have tried everything, the subquery works (I have tried it without quotes, without being cast to char, etc and it returns all of the element_id's I need to query in the proper order. When I go to do the above query, for some reason, it returns nothing despite there being entries in the database that correspond to the element_id's from the subquery.

The result I would like is data_value of all elements of onetsoc_code = '11-1011.00' sorted first by scale_id 'IM' (importance) then based on the order of importance, the data_values of all elements of the above onetsoc_code given scale_id 'LV'. I don't need the data_values from the first query, just the second one based on scale_id 'LV'

I'm also going to have to do this across multiple tables 'skills', 'abilities', etc. so any way I can optimize this query would be tremendously helpful!

I strongly suspect I'm making a bonehead mistake. Can anyone help me untangle this?

Comment: Please include input and output table in your question .

Comment: @HirenDhaduk Added input and output tables, sorry for the poor formatting

Comment: would you mind using [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)??

Comment: not sure but your Subquery within "in clause" seems problem, What is the output when you run that subquery only. it should return one column, and multiple rows, only, if not then make it that way to return only Element_id as you need and it will fix your query.

Comment: you are using group_concat but there is no group_by clause

Comment: @sumit if I remove the group concatenation it works but returns end results in the wrong order (ie not sorted by the data value desc when scale_id is "im".  The sub query produces the proper ordering of element Ids but the main query just sorts them alphabetically with no regard to the order of the subquery

Comment: What should I group by @koala_dev ?

Comment: See, I just told you sql logical error, to sort data you have to use Order by in your outer query, if not, possible then use the complete query as Subquery to another query which do the sorting, it is hard to tell as I still do not make sense with your data, but I think you can simply use Order by in outer part.

Comment: @sumit I tried that first, but I need the data sorted first according to the sub query then again according to the outer. Using order by in the outer in this case only sorts the outer query right but the inner queries order is disregarded?

Comment: well you can do this trick, create a View from inner query with Order by [as order by doesn't work on Inner sub query], but it works in View, then use that view as your subquery.

Comment: @SumitGupta can you show me what that might look like in SQL, I don't think I'm quite understanding you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a join would do what you want

```
SELECT a.element_id, a.data_value 
FROM skills as a, skills as b
WHERE a.element_id=b.element_id
and b.onetasoc_code='11-1011.00' and b.scale_id='IM'
AND a.onetsoc_code = '11-1011.00' 
AND a.scale_id = 'LV'
order by b.data_value desc
```

Comment: returned an empty results set the same as before :-(

Comment: Sorry mistake with the last and should be a.scale_id='LV' not b.scale_id

Comment: So when I want to add more tables to this (skills, abilities, etc) assuming they retain the same schema, do I need to change anything?

Comment: i.e. joining 4 tables based on the same concept

Comment: join can be made of any number of table. But lot of table to join means a little slower output.

Comment: Yes same concept.  Make sure you have indexes on the join keys (element_id in this case)

Comment: The tables are properly indexed. My one concern is that since it is a self join, is there any special syntax for doing multiple self joins that may be different from doing a standard multi-table join? The element_id's differ across the tables but the onetsoc_codes will be used as the common id. Sorry to badger @noz

Comment: No, self joins are no different - just makes the query a little more confusing!